# css automatically expand floating element (unknown widths)

Tags: html, css, width, css-float

My horizontal navigation bar looks like this:

```
| MENU-ITEM 1 | MENU-ITEM-2 | MENU-ITEM 3 | SEARCH FIELD              |
```

The menu-items have equal width, but since the website is cms-driven, the count of items and therefore the width of the menu-item-list will change.

I'm looking for a CSS solution for automatically stretching the search-field on the right to use 100% of the remaining space inside the navigation bar. The navigation-bar's total width is static (about 950px).

html is something like this, but maybe I need wrappers anyway:

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul id="nav-items">
      <li class="nav-item">MENU-ITEM 1</li>
      <li class="nav-item">MENU-ITEM 1</li>
      <li class="nav-item">MENU-ITEM 1</li>
   </ul>
   <div id="search-cont">
      <input id="search">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with the basics: http://jsfiddle.net/Qg2ag/

The idea is:

1. The wrapper of an input field must have `display:block` and `overflow:hidden`.
2. The menu near it must have the `float:left` and the items in it must be `inline` or `inline-block`.

So, the floated block *eats* it's width from the block with an overflow, so you can set `width: 100%` in it safely. And I've added `padding-right: 6px` to the input's wrapper so there is no need in ajusting it's width or using other box model. Of course the size of this padding can vary if you'd change the input's style.

Comment: works well, but the "display: block" is redundant for the div in your fiddle and I prefer "display: inline" to "display: inline-block", since it has better support (afaik). Correct me, if you think they are required, e.g. due to better compatibility across browsers

Comment: If you don't need the `inline-block`s, then you don't need them, but the browser support for them near as perfect (in IE you can use `display:inline;zoom:1` hack to enable `inline-block` behavior. And about redundant `display:block` — I've added it for bullet-proof: if the `div` suddenly'd become `span` it would be better to have some extra styles. Im my practice the actual `tag`s can vary.

Comment: Why not set the `input` to `display:block` instead of adding a wrap block element `div` for the `input`?

Comment: @hguser, try it yourself. You'll find out that input can't have width: auto, so you couldn't stretch it to the remaining space, it would have always fixed width. That's where the wrapper goes with automatic width.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps if you use `display: inline;` and `float: left;` on the `li`-elements.
This will keep them in one line. You can style these tags now. If you're using `a`-tags inside the `li`s you may consider styling these instead of the `li`s.

The search-bar will then be displayed in one line with these elements but also remain at a width of 100%.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drublic/VGCK2/).

Comment: it's not the problem to keep them in one line, but the question how to get the input-field resized automatically to fill the remaining space. the width of the search-field doesn't change in your fiddle when you resize the results-window.